# Binding winform label to function call

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a label in my application which is currently bound to a enum property on my source object.  I want to instead bind it to the result of a function call with that enum as the parameter.  Is there a way to do this without modifying the source object to have another property?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can only bind to properties on objects. You could create a new object inheriting from the original one containing a new property that returns as its value the function that takes the enum.

Comment: @CR41G14 - The code is pretty useless here.  It's just typical databinding.  `RMADetailBindingSource.DataSource = rma.RMADetails;` and `this.label3.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.RMADetailBindingSource, "Condition", true));`  `Condition` is an enum value.

Comment: @C.M. - That's kindof what I thought, but I'm hoping that I was wrong.  If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it tomorrow if no one else comes up with an actual way to do it.